# Printing out a sorted array by calling a method in another class that refers to another method Java Eclipse

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, methods, printing

I am having trouble using methods in another class. I have to call a method that calls another method to sort an array of strings with a bubble-sort.

the code:

```
    /**
 * My pride and joy, the bubble sort.
 * @return 
 */
public void BubbleSort(){

    boolean run = true;
    String temp;

    while (run)
    {
        run = false;

            for(int i = 0; i <stringArray.length - 1; i++)
            {

                if(stringArray[i].compareToIgnoreCase( stringArray[i+1]) > 0)
                {

                    temp = stringArray[i];

                    stringArray[i] = stringArray[i+1];

                    stringArray[i+1] = temp;

                    run = true;
                }// end of if
            }// end of for
    }// end of while

    System.out.println(stringArray);


}// end of BubbleSort




public void PrintSortedString(){
    BubbleSort();
}
```

those are the two methods.

when calling it from the driver class ( note the methods are in another class )
i call it like so

```
stringUtility.PrintSortedString();
```

The input is ::

```
    Please enter names:
z
a
Your names:
[z, a]
[Ljava.lang.String;@4efe03b3 // this is where it should priont [a,z]
```

what did i do wrong?

Comment: Small Java coding style tip - it's generally accepted to start method names with a lower case letter and class names with an upper case letter. For example, `public class MyClass` and `public void doSomething()`.

Comment: @Meesh Please don't modify posted code except to format it, you've changed the method signatures from what the OP posted, which could course more confusion when people are trying to answer the OP's question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are seeing

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@4efe03b3
```

is the result of

```
System.out.println(stringArray);
```

which internally calls `stringArray.toString()` and prints the result of that.

This behavior applies to all Objects. If you want custom string message, you need to have your class implement a custom `toString()` method instead of relying on [`Object#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). Since you can't change the `String[]` class, you need to iterate over the elements yourself.

Alternatively, you can rely on the `Arrays` class that is part of the JDK

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
System.out.println(stringArray);
```

Try using...

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringArray));
```

The first is printing information about the array, the second is printing the content...

**Updated**

*IF* you want the methods to return the result of the sort operation, then you need to define the methods to do so...

```
public String[] BubbleSort(){
    /*...*/
    return stringArray;
}// end of BubbleSort

public String[] PrintSortedString(){
    return BubbleSort();
}
```

This would then allow you to use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(stringUtility.PrintSortedString())`

You should also take the time to read through [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html)

Comment: Makes sense, First I tried to use     Arrays.toString(stringUtility.PrintSortedString(); within the driver class. which would throw errors at me

Comment: @user2817719 The method `PrintSortedString` doesn't return anything.

Comment: It was never supposed to.